# Issue with using particles.js as a website background

Tags: html, particles.js

Hope everyone is doing good.
I recently tried to use Particles.js(by Vincent Garreau) as a background for my portfolio website(https://harshsinghal.me). However I am not sure as to where should I add the particles div (with an id="particles-js") so that they span the entire website. As of now, if you visit my website and enable dark mode(cause currently the particles are white) and scroll at the end, you will see the particles. But instead of them being at the end, I want them to be everywhere in my website(as a background). Please tell if I need to add any css or change the location of the div.
Thanks!
Harsh

Comment: Please see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Try following this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/js-background-effects-particlesjs